# Setting NOEXEC ON still executes "USE" statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

When executing the following in SSMS;

```
if not exists (select * from sys.databases where name = 'SWFUAT')
begin
    print 'The UAT database (SWFUAT) does not exist...'
    set noexec on;
end
go

use SWFUAT;
go
```

The following is displayed;

> The UAT database (SWFUAT) does not exist...
>       Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
>       Database 'SWFUAT' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Shouldn't the compiler just ignore the "`use`" statement?

Comment: @shA.t you were correct however the documentation states;
>When SET NOEXEC is ON, SQL Server compiles each batch of Transact-SQL statements but does not execute them.
And the example [Microsoft][MSLink] provides shows `noexec` being used as shown above?
[MSLink]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(NOEXEC_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true

Comment: "USE is executed at both compile and execution time and takes effect immediately. " - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-NZ/library/ms188366.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to execute

```
use SWFUAT;
```

only when the `SWFUAT` database is exist.

Unfortunately because of this remark

> USE is executed at both compile and execution time and takes effect immediately. Therefore, statements that appear in a batch after the USE statement are executed in the specified database.

described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-NZ/library/ms188366.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you can't simply use the `SET NOEXEC` in your case.
To achieve what you need you should replace your code with for example this

```
if not exists (select * from sys.databases where name = 'SWFUAT')
begin
    print 'The UAT database (SWFUAT) does not exist...' 
end else begin
    use SWFUAT;
end
go
```